# Why sorting of numericcolumn does not work in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, ag-grid

I am try to use sorting in the ag-grid for a numeric column with decimal numbers but I am not getting the sorting correct. Why is that so?

What could be a possible solution for this?

The below screenshot gives an example how the sorted column looks like. Here the first column is sorted.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a text sort. Is the data actually number type? You may need to provide a custom comparator to get teh desired result.

Comment: I provided a custom comparator. What should it look like

`comparator: function(a, b){ if(a > b) return 1; else if( a < b) return -1; else return 0;`

Comment: But it did not work either. Could not understand why

Comment: What do you get if you do `typeof a`? Do you get 'number' or 'string'? If it's string then you need a parseFloat to convert it to a number before the comparison.

Comment: did find a solution i have the same problem even when i converted them to numbers with parseFloat